# One touch embedded survey in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, survey

Is there a way we can implement one click survey that will be embedded within an email in SF Marketing cloud directly without any third party integration?

Comment: As long as you understand any link in an email will be redirected to a web page, then yes this is possible. I would recommend you create a landing page in CloudPages to display the confirmation page and update a DE with the survey result. If you provide your sample survey question (I assume this is a single questions with a multiple choice answer), then I will provide some sample code to get you started.

Comment: @EliotHarper Yes if i build something on cloud page then i can document the survey response. However i don't want to redirect to another page. It will be a email and in the end a there will be a block asking "Was this email helpful" with options Very Helpful, Help, Not helpful. mostly with a images/icons. when someone clicks on the icon the response should be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to enable this functionality (survey submission within the email, without being redirected to a web page) would be to use client-side JavaScript, which is only supported in Lotus Notes and Thunderbird email clients.

Comment: If it's not too time critical and if journey builder is available it would be possible to use engagement splits and contact update activities. However, approach Eliot described in his first comment is what I personally would endorse as best practice as it reacts in "real time".